# Repeat an Image according to count

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Basically I need to display "Ratings" with the help of image, I need to repeat an Image according to number count. Like if variable count is 3 then image will be shown thrice. How to do this?

[image: Like this]

Comment: you can try to add image programmatically inside loop of count

Comment: @BaSha Yeah ! that's what i wanna know, add image according to loop count but how to add image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run for loop and add images as subview to some view.

```
-(UIView*)createRatingView :(NSInteger)stars {
     UIView* rating = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,20)]; //set proper frame.. In this example (20*5) + (5*4) where 20 is width of image and 5 is padding between stars

     for (i=1;i<=5;i++) {
         int xPos = (i-1)*(20+5); // assuming 20 is width of image and 5 is padding between 2 stars
         UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos,0,20,20)];
         if (stars<= i) {
             img.image = [UIImage named:@"goldStar"];
         }
         else {
             img.image = [UIImage named:@"grayStar"];
         }
         [rating addSubview : img];
     }
     return rating;
}
```